# Which journaling system best prevents torn writes like Windows NTFS?

Tags: filesystem

Which journaling system best prevents torn writes like Windows NTFS?

I found this on "torn writes", but to be honest I do not understand the explanation.

http://www.joshodgers.com/tag/torn-write/

Comment: What criteria are you using to define "best"? And why specifically one form of data corruption? Data can be corrupted many ways.

Comment: @Nmath Your link is the same as at the very top.